# Entity exists multiple times in jpa cache

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-3

I have a funny caching problem with my jpa 2.01, glassfish v3 server.

I insert a telefonnumber to a existing customer via Jax-Rs POST. 
Afterwards I read all telefonnumbers from that customer in a separate jax-rs GET request. 
In the GET the new number is missing. When I repeat the request after 5 seconds it contains the number. I assume the GET is reading the telefonnumbers from a old instance of the customer that is stored in the jpa cache. When I evict the customer from the cache after inserting the new number my problem is "solved".

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="elm", name="CUSTOMER")
@Cache(expiry=5000)
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String no;

    private String name;....

@OneToMany(
        cascade=CascadeType.ALL, 
        mappedBy="customer", 
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
        targetEntity=Comm.class
    )
private List<Comm> comms = new Vector<Comm>(0);
}

@Entity
@Table(schema="elm", name="COMM")
@Cache(expiry=Constants.SHORT_CACHE_PERIODE_MS)
public class Comm implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String value;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="elmID")
private Customer customer;


}
```

I add the two entities to each other by :

```
    Customer e = em.find(Customer.class, cusID);
    c.setCustomer(e);
    e.getComms().add(c);
```

I don't call persist or merge. Because of cascade=CascadeType.ALL it inserts the new phone number into the database.

I think there is two instances of the Customer class floating arround. How can I log the Customer class instance. I need s.t. that shows me that there a two different ones. S.t. like customer.getJPAIdentificationId();

The changes on the entities are dann in a @Stateless Bean that contains a 
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "DATA")
    private EntityManager em;

Thanks Hasan

Comment: How are you obtaining EntityManagers to do the reading?  Each EM has its own cache, so any Customer reading through one before the change will never show the change unless the em is cleared, closed or the entity is refreshed through that EM.  Each Em will return you its own managed instance of the Customer entity, which will be a completely different instance from each other - keeping changes local until their transactions are commited by design.

Comment: I use a stateless bean and a PersitenceContext annotation to inject the entitymanager. How would I configure everything to really have a benefit cacheing. Does it also mean that all entities are gone after the one request is finished? Also the @ReadOnly Entities?